# Android screen screw up. (colored lines, no exception, black screen)

Tags: android, crash

A few user reported this issue (Dell, Samsung device). I checked the crash logs, no crash. I don't know about any exception, but it's possible.

Somebody saw something like this ? Or a black screen maybe ?

[image]

Comment: Yuck. What does your app do? Does it use OpenGL, NDK, anything worth mentioning?

Comment: No, just a simple app with 5 fragments in a viewpager + actionbar. I don't know to what to think. The app size is around 5MB.

Comment: We found the issue. It was a problem changing the Window.SECURE flag onResume.... that messed up the screen (or black screen) in some devices...